# What exception should I throw for a failed file parsing?

Tags: c#, parsing, exception

I have a method parsing a file. However, this parsing could fail anytime, depending on various conditions (not-so-cautious user playing with the file, for example).

```
public string ParseDatFile(string datFile)
{
    string[] deezLines = File.ReadAllLines(datFile);

    // We're searching for an essential data inside the file.
    bool daEssentialDataFound = false;
    foreach (string datLine in deezLines)
    {
        if (datLine.Contains("daEssentialData"))
        {
            daEssentialDataFound = true;
            break;
        }
    }

    if (!daEssentialDataFound)
        throw new WhatShouldIThrowException("yo dood where's da essential data in " + datFile + "?");

    DoStuffWith(deezLines);
}
```

**Is there an exception I could use in such a scenario?** I thought about:

- **FormatException**: not really clear about the issue,
- **Custom exception**: I do not have any special treatment for the exception I'm throwing, so I'd rather avoid using a custom exception, even though that's always a way to settle things down.

Comment: As an aside, you can simplify above with: `if(!deezLines.Any(l => l.Contains("daEssentialData")))`

Comment: @Tim Indeed, yet I'm still quite unexperienced with da Linq.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[FileFormatException](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/system.io.fileformatexception(v=vs.110).aspx) should be fine :

> The exception that is thrown when an input file or a data stream that
>   is supposed to conform to a certain file format specification is
>   malformed.

You can optionally provide the uri and a descriptive error message.

---

If you don't want to reference `WindowsBase` then you may create your own exception specific to your format. Based on the fact there is an `XmlException` thrown by [`XmlReader.Read`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/system.xml.xmlreader.read.aspx).

Comment: I wouldn't use that. This is defined in `WindowsBase`, so this won't be available for many projects (console, ASP.Net...) and you don't want to add a reference for this class only.

Comment: It's not even available in winforms by default, is it?

Comment: @TimSchmelter No it isn't

Answer (score 4):

I would throw a custom exception since that increases readability and allows to catch that specifc exception:

```
public class InvalidFileFormatException : System.FormatException
{
    public InvalidFileFormatException(string exText) : base(exText) { }
}

// you could even provide an exception if a single line has an invalid format
public class SpecificLineErrorException : InvalidFileFormatException 
{
    public string Line { get; set; }
    public SpecificLineErrorException(string exText, string line) : base(exText) 
    {
        this.Line = line;
    }
}
```

Now your method can look like(also linqified it a little bit:

```
public string ParseDatFile(string datFile)
{
    string[] deezLines = File.ReadAllLines(datFile);
    if(!deezLines.Any(l => l.Contains("daEssentialData")))
        throw new InvalidFileFormatException("yo dood where's da essential data in " + datFile + "?");
    DoStuffWith(deezLines);
}
```

Comment: But why would anyone catch that specific exception? What would I do with a `SpecificLineErrorException` versus a `InvalidFileFormatException` from the application's perspective?

Comment: @PrestonGuillot: if you parse a huge file you often don't want to cancel the whole parsing process just because of few invalid lines. But you want to log this or do some other kind of things with them.  A good example is the [`MalformedLineException`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualbasic.fileio.malformedlineexception(v=vs.110).aspx)` used by the [`TextFieldParser`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualbasic.fileio.textfieldparser.errorline(v=vs.110).aspx) class. By the way, that exception would also be a good built-in candidate ;)

Comment: [This other popular CSV-Parser](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/9258/A-Fast-CSV-Reader) also has specific exceptions like `MissingFieldCsvException` or `MalformedCsvException` and an option to set useful actions like `AdvanceToNextLine`, `RaiseEvent` or `ThrowError` according to the exception type.

Comment: @Tim Often you don't, but I indicated in my question that I wouldn't be having any specific control for this exception, so if parsing fails, I will just catch the base Exception and log da crap out of it. Anyway, this is a good way to handle things.